# How to remove an arbitrary element from a standard heap in c++?

Tags: c++, heap

I've got some code that continuously extracts the max valued object from a heap and processes it. However, during processing of the max, other objects in the heap are affected, and may need to get deleted. Roughly:

```
vector<HeapEntry*> myHeap = vector<HeapEntry*>();
fillHeap(myHeap, someData);
make_heap(myHeap.begin(), myHeap.end());
while (!myHeap.empty())
{
    HeapEntry* hp = myHeap.front();
    HeapEntry* neighbor = hp->getNeighbor();
    if (someCondition)
    {
        remove(myHeap, neighbor);
    }
    //more processing of hp
}
```

And the remove function:

```
void remove(vector<HeapEntry*> myHeap, HeapEntry* toRemove)
{
    for (it = myHeap.begin(); it != myHeap.end(); it++)
    {
        if (*it == hp)
        {
            myHeap.erase(it);
            break;
        }
    }
    make_heap(myHeap.begin(), myHeap.end());
}
```

This runs and gives correct output. But it's slow as all hell: 2 minutes to process a 40kb file (the size of the heap is linear in the size of the file). Anyway it needs to be more efficient.

The remove function ends up getting called roughly n times, where n is the size of the heap. So having that linear search makes the entire algorithm O(n^2). I think that's the problem, and I believe this can run in O(n*log(n)).

My goal is to do the remove function in O(log(n)) time. Something like:

- Go straight to the target element
- Switch it with the last element
- pop_heap(myHeap.begin(), myHeap.end()); myHeap.pop_back();
- make_heap(myHeap.begin(), myHeap.end());

I'm not quite sure how to implement this (I'm hardly familiar with the stl heap).
Does anyone know how to do this without doing the linear search?

Comment: exemplary! first make it right, then make it fast.

Comment: Is the order of HeapEntry objects important?

Comment: @Lou The order is important, in the sense of maintaining the heap property.

Answer (score 6):

The simple approach is **not** to remove the elements you think you want to remove. Instead, you'd maintain a priority queue to determine the next max element and a `std::set<HeapEntry*>` of removed element. When getting the max element you check if it is in the set of removed elements and you just remove it from the heap, trying the next element. Depending on the number of potentially removed elements, you might want to also remove the element from the set of removed elements when you remove it from the heap.

Instead of removing elements from the heap, you just add them to the set of removed elements. This way the heap elements still stay logarithmic and you may have up to O(n log n) operations on the set of elements.

The other alternative would be the use of a node-based priority queue to efficiently find the position of a node in the heap. For example, Boost provides a Fibonacci-heap as part of the Boost Graph Library. You can track the position of an element there. However, node-based heaps tend to perform slower on practical problem sizes due to their overhead when rearranging elements.

Comment: I like the first approach, and am currently trying to implement something similar. I use a simple boolean flag in my HeapEntry class, and set it to false instead of removing it. When I extract the max, I then check this flag, and skip processing if it's false. Unfortunately, it's giving me runtime errors (invalid heap) so I need to quickly figure that out as well.

Comment: Make sure you don't change the attribute(s) which determine the priority of you elements after you put them into the queue! The heap would need to be told about a change of an elements priority. It is possible to implement a heap supporting a corresponding option but it again needs the ability to track the location.

Comment: right, that would definitely screw things up, but I use a different field called valid, and only for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for all your replies. I decided to go with an approach that does in fact delete the HeapEntries when they are no longer valid. Actually I tried adding a valid flag to HeapEntry, and I think this would have worked if it hadn't been for some other errors that I've since fixed. Anyhow, here's how I ended up solving it.

To reiterate, I needed the ability to delete an element from a heap given just a pointer to that element. The problem with that was, the pointer didn't tell me anything about the *position* of the element in the heap. So, I decided to store the position, keep it updated whenever elements moved, and write a function to delete from a heap given a position. Simply put, a heap is stored as an array, and the positions of the elements define the parent/child relationships. An element's parent should be at location floor((myPos - 1) / 2), and its children should be at positions 2*myPos+1 and 2*myPos+2. I realized I could write a remove(position) function, and while swapping elements to maintain the heap property, could swap their stored positions as well. Here's a link to the the result, and it sped up execution by a factor of 5 or 10:

https://github.com/yankrasny/CC-Heap-with-random-delete

Comment: The code you have for random delete only percolates down. However there is no guarantee that it is sufficient. Consider the case where the data is partitioned into 3 sets. Root, High, Low where every element in High is larger than every element in Low. Consider the case where elements from High form the left-sub tree of the root, and Low forms the right sub-tree of the root and N(High) > N(low) such that, the last element is in lefts sub-tree. In this case when you delete an element from the right sub-tree, the last element comes from High (left sub-tree) and needs to be percolated up.

Answer (score 1):

The stl philosophy is to reflect on your algorithm first, and then choose your data structure.  Your're doing it the other way around.

If you plan to remove elements from your data structure in a 'random' order, you're probably better with a `priority_queue` or even a linked `list`.  (Be careful, though: iterators may be invalidated after removing from some stl containers).

Comment: How would a priority_queue be different in that sense? Isn't it just a wrapper around those very same make_heap(), push_heap, etc. functions? Also, I would love to find a data structure that does what I need, that is be able to extract max, as well as delete given a pointer to a random entry.

Answer (score 1):

I'm almost 7 years too late but hoping it will help someone else. A few good options have been discussed above and I'd just like to add another one.

If you use a balanced BST (i.e. `set<HeapEntry*>`), you can find max and delete an element in O(log n). This will make your entire algorithm O(n log n).

Note 1: if you have duplicates, use `multiset` instead and delete using `<ms>.erase(<ms>.find(<obj>))` to delete only one occurrence of `<obj>`. `<ms>.erase(<obj>)` deletes all occurrences of `<obj>`.

Note 2: find max can be made O(1) using the fact that if an element is removed, all iterators, pointers and references to other elements remain valid ([source](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/erase/)). You cache iterator to the max element and update it for every insertion or deletion, if needed.